# RSS криво отображается в разных браузерах (Django)

Tags: python, rss, django

По нижеописсаной проблеме выяснилось что подобное только на последних версиях браузелов Хром и Лисы. В IE как ни странно все отображается корректно (что самое обидное - сайт то от IE я закрыл вообще :) )
Помогите привести к единому стилю/виду, чтобы везде отображалось корректно.

По стандартному Django мануалу, с немногим недоумением, но настроил себе RSS на рессурсе, однако спустя какое-то время вместо RSS ленты стало выдавать просто XML который генерил двиг, при этом кодировка была win-1251 хотя в самой ленте четко прописано:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Вот скрин кусочка выдаваемого XML вместо RSS, которую я жду.

[image]

Проект на Django1.3, python2.6

Comment: А в базе правильные кодировки? Можно еще в настройки веб-сервера заглянуть.

Comment: В БД все ок, ну и настройки все нормально, все страницы норм отдаёт, да и РСС раньше работал, хотя как правку написал, возможно в ранних версиях браузеров работает норм. в IE до сих пор норм работает, видимо проблема на стороне клиента, но как унифицировать для всех браузеров ХЗ.

Answer (score 1):

В общем кодировку выдает на самом деле utf-8, однако браузеры почему-то автоматически неправильно определяют кодировку? 
Возможно некоторые браузеры смотрят на кодировку в документе в первую очередь, а другие на кодировку http-заголовков и возможно нужный заголовок не отдается и следуется явно его передать, кажется там должен быть "Accept-Charset: utf-8". 
Но это лишь предположения, посмотрите в браузере http заголовки ответа, которые передаются при запросе фида.